# How to weigh residuals based on x-interval in the nls() function in R?

Tags: r, residuals, nonlinear-regression, fitting, nls

A plot of my data and fit:

```
ggplot(ahn.res, aes(rds,ror_rr)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "nls",
              formula = y ~ 1-exp(-A*x^B)+0.02799777,
              method.args = list(start=c(A=2,B=3)),
              se=F) +
  ylab("y") +
  xlab("x")
```

[image]

I'm interested in the max value of the second derivative of this function, corresponding to the red point on this graph. As I have more data points in the higher portion of graph, does the **nls() function** skew the fit towards this high data density region of the graph? If so, is there a way to **weigh the residuals** based on the **interval of x**, such that a higher interval gets a higher weight?